# SAP Hana SQL Type mapped to OData Edm.boolean

Tags: hana-xs

In the SAP HANA developer guide there is a list explaining SQL - EDM Type mapping

Missing is how to map from a SQL Type to Edm.Boolean, anyone know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the SAP HANA developer guide (SPS 07) it also says that the OData implementation in SAP HANA XS supports **only** those SQL types listed in the mentioned list/table. Therefore Edm.Boolean is not supported.

A workaround could be to use **Edm.Byte** instead of Edm.Boolean which is mapped to the **TinyInt** HANA SQL Type. If you only want to have a true/false or 0/1 value I think the TinyInt SQL Type is the closest you can get to a Boolean.

Comment: thanks - I get that the SQL Types are predefined, in ABAP and other techniques you can change the default Edm mappings via config, thought there may have been something similar, would be handy

Comment: I had the same thought about using 0/1, then i remembered in js x = 0; (x) === true, I know (!!x) === false but want something that works out of the box

Comment: @Jasper_07 so in the end - did it solve your problem? In case yes, would be happy if you mark it as answered :) Thanks!